# Incorrect user-level lock name - Local Vagrant Environment - Craft 3

Tags: craft3, mysql

When creating a new field, I received a Database Exception error -

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 3057 Incorrect user-level lock name '/var/www/storage/runtime/compiled_classes/ElementQueryBehavior.php'.

Loading an older database backup did not resolve the error, and neither did checking out an older branch. I am unable to access the panel or the site itself.

Installed Plugins

- SEOmatic
- Element API
- SuperTable

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

[image: Error Screenshot]

Edit: After dropping/creating the database multiple times, I am now getting this error instead

[image: Content Behavior Not Found]

Edit 2: Here is a link to the full stack trace, which was posted to imgur due to the length

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktowh.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just  ran into the exact same error on my Vagrant/Homestead environment when creating a field just with the lock name '/home/vagrant/code/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_classes/ContentBehavior.php'.

After getting this error the page cannot be accessed at all.

I'm using SuperTable, too.

The error itself seems to come from MySQL 5.7 where there is a character limit for the user-level lock names of 64 characters. Here the GET_LOCK statement fails. I just don't know how to fix it right now.

Comment: If you're using Homestead, just switch it to use MariaDB and away you go. You just change a line in the YAML and do `homestead up --provision`

Comment: Is MariaDB the preferred option for Craft 3? If this is an avoidable error, I would prefer to just avoid it, but if using MySQL will continue to cause issues I would definitely want to look into MariaDB

Comment: Thank you @andrew.welch

Seems to work so far. I ran into problems with MySQL and Craft in different environments. Hope this has an end now. :)

Comment: Agree with stepbyweb, thank you for the solution Andrew. I was also able to resolve the issue by dropping in MariaDB

Comment: Both MySQL and MariaDB are fully supported by Craft; this issue is something I'd probably get in touch with the folks at P&T about: support@craftcms.com -- it nothing else other than to make sure they are aware of it (and they may have another workaround as well). I personally prefer MariaDB, but either it or MySQL are both equally good choices for Craft CMS (as is Postgres).

Comment: Is there a chance that either of you changed something in `app.php` or such to change the default behavior? Craft normally uses file-base locks for these things... I'm puzzled as to how this could be ending up in your db?

Comment: @TheCodeNomad If there's any chance you could share the full stack trace leading up to that error, that'd be helpful in debugging, too.

Comment: @andrew.welch I did add the mutex component to my app.php in order to resolve a previous issue

Comment: Brad, I updated my question with an image of the stack trace

Comment: Thanks, @TheCodeNomad - this shouldn't be an issue going forward with https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/dd21625170255df8338385449f2bb4620b5fc56e